Posting comment as a user on github on a private repository
I'm working on an ap using github and slack API.
There's a feature that should allow comments from slack using modals to be posted on the changes made on a github pull request whenenever a pull request is created.
It keeps throwing this error:
Failed to access repository:
{
   "message":"Not Found",
   "documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest/repos/repos#get-a-repository",
   "status":"404"
}

Image below for full error message
error message
This is the github API code:
async postComment(
    comment: string,
    html_url: string,
    userAccessToken: string,
    filename?: string,
    commitId?: string,
  ): Promise<void> {
    try {
      if (!(await this.verifyAccessToken(userAccessToken))) {
        throw new Error('Invalid or expired access token');
      }

      const [, , , owner, repo, , pullNumber] = html_url.split('/');
      if (!owner || !repo || !pullNumber) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid URL: ${html_url}`);
      }

      console.log(
        `Parsed URL: owner=${owner}, repo=${repo}, pullNumber=${pullNumber}`,
      );

      await this.testRepoAccess(owner, repo, userAccessToken);

      if (!(await this.checkRepoAccess(owner, repo, userAccessToken))) {
        throw new Error('Cannot access the specified repository');
      }

      if (
        !(await this.checkIssueExistence(
          owner,
          repo,
          pullNumber,
          userAccessToken,
        ))
      ) {
        throw new Error('Cannot access the specified issue or pull request');
      }

      const apiUrl = `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/issues/${pullNumber}/comments`;

      console.log(`Constructed API URL: ${apiUrl}`);

      const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
          Authorization: `token ${userAccessToken}`,
          Accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          body: comment,
          commit_id: commitId,
          path: filename,
          start_line: 1,
          position: 1,
        }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        throw new Error(
          `GitHub API error: ${response.status} ${JSON.stringify(errorData)}`,
        );
      }

      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log('Comment posted successfully:', responseData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error posting comment:', error);
      throw new CoefficientError('Failed to post PR comment', 'POST_COMMENT');
    }
  }

Image here: Github API code
Am i missing something?
I have written methods to test the token validadity and it's valid.
And the comments is being sent from slack, which means the issue is not from there.
I also have owner access in the organisation.
What i expect is the comment to be posted successfully.
But I'm not getting that.

Looks like a simple typo. See https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/comments?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-review-comment-for-a-pull-request. The /issues/ part in your URL should be /pulls/

@Phil I have also tried pull.
I get the same response when I use pulls too.

Your Authentication header value doesn't match the documentation either. It clearly states you should be using a Bearer token

Have you also verified that your parameters are all correct? Grab the details or URL you logged and see if you can directly open the web URL https://github.com/${owner}/${repo}/pull/${pullNumber}

I think I have tired that before but let try that now and see if I can.

@Phil I've checked. The parameters on used on the link, takes me to the pull request on GitHub which means they are correct.

Let me change the token header and test again.
